# How to resolve JSON Schema $ref to file in parent directory

Tags: jsonschema

I have some some legacy draft-04 schema that I am trying to get to resolve a $ref to a file in parent directory. Several attempts at various dotted paths have failed to resolve this ref for me.

Child Schema

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "emailDelivery/delivery.delivery.config.emailSituations",
  "description": "desc",
  "type": "array",
  "items": {
  "description": "desc",
  "type": "object",
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "delivery.delivery.config.meta" }
  ],
  "properties": {
    "name": {
      "description": "desc",
      "type": "string"
    },
  "conditions": {
    "description": "Wraps a query object",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "query": { "$ref": "../query.json#/query" }
    },
    "required": [ "query" ]
  },
  "body": {
    "description": "The body of the email message",
    "type": "string"
    }
  },
  "required": [ "name", "conditions", "body" ]
  }
}
```

Query.json lives in ../  relative to child above.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "id": "query",
  "description": "desc",
  "type": ["object", "null"],
  "properties": {
    "operator": {
      "description": "desc",
      "enum": [ "and", "or" ]
    },
    "rules": {
      "description": "Tdesc",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "anyOf": [
          { "$ref": "#/definitions/comparisonRule" },
          { "$ref": "#/definitions/groupRule" }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [ "operator", "rules" ],
  "definitions": {
    "comparisonRule": {
      "description": "desc",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "field": {
          "description": "desc",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "comparison": {
          "description": "desc",
          "enum": [ "is", "is not", "greater than", "less than" ]
        },
        "data": {
          "description": "desc",
          "type": [ "array", "string" ],
          "items": {
            "description": "desc",
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "required": [ "field", "comparison", "data" ]
    },
    "groupRule": {
      "description": "desc",
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "query": { "$ref": "query" }
      },
      "required": [ "query" ]
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am receiving:

```
Error: can't resolve reference file:../query.json#/query from id emailDelivery/delivery.delivery.config.emailSituations#
```

From what I understand, this pathing should work for ../query.json.

Comment: How does `"$ref": "delivery.delivery.config.meta"` resolve? As in, how does the JSON Schema library you're using know what file that URI relates to?

Comment: delivery.delivery.config.meta is in the same directory, not the parent and resolves.

Comment: You have a JSON Schema file in the same directory as the one which contains the $ref, called `delivery.delivery.config.meta`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
    "properties": {
      "query": { "$ref": "../query.json#/query" }
    },
```

try:

```
    "properties": {
      "query": { "$ref": "../query.json
    },
```

If you're linking to a specific property in that file, try:

```
    "properties": {
      "query": { "$ref": "../query.json#/properties/[name of property]" }
    },
```